Option clash for package asymptote
This is the error i encounter while using asymptote
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,stmaryrd,color,iftex}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand\myfontsize{\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{arcs}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

The /usepackage[inline]{asymptote} has the "Option clash for package asymptote" error.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

welcome! don't load it twice.

I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

are you really using tikz and xy and asymptote all in the same diagram? theer is nothing wrong with any of these systems but they are three competing and very large drawing systems and you use all three in one document????

as well as loading asymptote twice you are loading mathrsfs twice

LaTeX only loads packages once. You have
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

So LaTeX loads asymptote with no options. Then it loads mathtools. Now you ask it to load asymptote with the inline option. But that's not possible because the package has been loaded already.
The solution is to load the package only once with whichever options you need.
You also could avoid the problem by loading it with inline first, as LaTeX won't mind if an option is simply missing the second time.
Things get interesting if one package you load loads another with options and you'd like different options. Suppose mathtools loaded asymptote with the option frog and you want to load it with the option toad. You could just say
\usepackage[frog,toad]{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}

but then you'd have to know which options mathtools wanted and change them if they altered. A more robust solution would be
\PassOptionsToPackage{toad}{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}

Note: No amphibians were harmed in the writing of this answer.
